# MySQL&django hangs on huge session delete

Tags: python, mysql, django

I'm running django site with MySQL as DB back-end.
Finally i've got 3 millions rows in django_session table. Most of them are expired, thus i want to remove them.
But if i manually run  `delete from django_session where expire_date < "2011-04-18"` whole site seems to be hanged - it cannot be accessed via browser.

Why such kind of blocking is possible? How to avoid it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your table is `MyISAM`, `DELETE` operations lock the table and it is not accessible by the concurrent queries.

If there are many records to delete, the table is locked for too long.

Split your `DELETE` statement into several shorter batches.

Answer (score 1):

I am not MySQL expert, but I guess MySQL locks the table for the deleting and this might be MySQL transaction/backend related. When deleting is in progress MySQL blocks the access to the table from other connections. MyISAM and InnoDB backend behavior might differ. I suggest you study MySQL manual related to this: the problem is not limited to Django domain, but generally how to delete MySQL rows without blocking access to the table.

For the future reference I suggest you set-up a session cleaner task which will clear the sessions, let's say once in a day, from cron so that you don't end up with such huge table.

Comment: Yes, in the future don't let it grow that big. There is a management command that you can run periodically (perhaps with cron) that will remove expired rows.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the sample cleanup command - http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/?from=olddocs#clearing-the-session-table - which removes all expired sessions i think.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>If I recall correctly there is no index on the expire_date column</strike> Operating on a a lot of rows will take a while.  While that's happening it will keep a lock on the table too (in MyISAM at least).

You might be better off deleting based on primary key (e.g. id) until you have fewer rows in the django_session table.  Once you have fewer rows you can add an index to expire_date and make sure you run the [cleanup](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/?from=olddocs#clearing-the-session-table) command regularly.

You'll have to estimate where to start your deletion from, but assuming that you know that all rows with a id less than 2,900,000 need removing:

```
delete from django_session where id < 29000000;
```

To avoid locking the table for too long you might want to delete a few thousand rows at a time, each in their own transaction, e.g.

```
begin;
delete from django_session where id < 10000;
commit;
begin;
delete from django_session where id < 20000;
commit;
...
begin;
delete from django_session where id < 29000000;
commit;
```

Of course you should probably create a script to do this.

In general you want to delete fewer rows at a time.  It will take longer overall, but it shouldn't lock your site up for too long in one go.